# move csv data to zip archive as zipentry objects- constructor ZipEntry(Path) is undefined

Tags: java, file, opencv, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I have this method in my springboot application which is generating 3 CSV files (related to Employee, Customer and Building) inside custom_users directory with timestamp appended to its name as shown below.
The following code works fine for me.

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

    DataSource ds = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmtEmployee = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmtCompany = null; 
    PreparedStatement pstmBuilding = null; 

    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rsDemo = null;
    ResultSet rsCompany = null;
    ResultSet rsBuildings = null;


     String[] parts = msg.split("#");
     String requestID = parts[0].trim();
     String userName = parts[1].trim();
     String applicationName = parts[2].trim();

    logger.info("Request ID "+requestID);
    logger.info("User Name "+userName);
    logger.info("Application Name "+applicationName);



     try {

            ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
            conn = ds.getConnection();  

            /*===========================================================================*/
            /*    Code to generate a employee CSV file              */ 
            /*===========================================================================*/
            pstmtEmployee = conn.prepareStatement(getPatientEmployeeSQL);
            pstmtEmployee.setString(1, requestID);
            rsDemo = pstmtEmployee.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsDemo.getMetaData();



             Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
             Files.createDirectories(dir);

             Path file = dir.resolve("employee_custom_file" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
             try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(file))) {
                 writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
             }

             logger.info("Employee File Generated");


             /*===========================================================================*/
             /*    Code to generate a company CSV file                                      */ 
             /*===========================================================================*/

            pstmtCompany = conn.prepareStatement(getCompanySQL);
            pstmtCompany.setString(1, requestID);
            rsCompany = pstmtCompany.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rsmdFacts = rsCompany.getMetaData();


             Path filecompany = dir.resolve("company_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
             try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(filecompany))) {
                 writer.writeAll(rsCompany, true);
             }

             logger.info("Company CSV File Generated");


             /*===========================================================================*/
             /*    Code to generate a building CSV file                                 */ 
             /*===========================================================================*/

             pstmBuilding = conn.prepareStatement(getBuildingSQL);
              pstmBuilding.setString(1, requestID);
              rsBuildings = pstmBuilding.executeQuery();

               ResultSetMetaData rsmdBuildings = rsBuildings.getMetaData();


                Path fileBuildings = dir.resolve("building_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                 try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(fileBuildings))) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsBuildings, true);
                 }

                logger.info("Buildings CSV File Generated");




            }
        catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
        }
        finally {
            //resource closing statements

        }   



}
```

**My questions:**

I am trying to modify the `CSVWriter`'s constructor in sucn a way that the CSV data should go directly into the ZIP archive as ZipEntry objects.

So I made the changes in the above code (visible after this line `ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsDemo.getMetaData();` in the code below). Right now I am just trying to put one file into ZIP archive to test but I noticed following errors:

***Error on Line #173 says:*** The constructor ZipEntry(Path) is undefined.

***Error on Line #175 says:*** Multiple markers at this line (one out of 2 errors is The constructor CSVWriter(ZipOutputStream) is undefined) .

Screenshot from my eclipse: 
[image]

How should I handle ZipEntry's and CSVWriter's constructor part ?

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtEmployee = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmtCompany = null; 
        PreparedStatement pstmBuilding = null; 

        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSet rsDemo = null;
        ResultSet rsCompany = null;
        ResultSet rsBuildings = null;


         String[] parts = msg.split("#");
         String requestID = parts[0].trim();
         String userName = parts[1].trim();
         String applicationName = parts[2].trim();

        logger.info("Request ID "+requestID);
        logger.info("User Name "+userName);
        logger.info("Application Name "+applicationName);



         try {

                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();  

                /*===========================================================================*/
                /*    Code to generate a employee CSV file              */ 
                /*===========================================================================*/
                pstmtEmployee = conn.prepareStatement(getPatientEmployeeSQL);
                pstmtEmployee.setString(1, requestID);
                rsDemo = pstmtEmployee.executeQuery();

                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsDemo.getMetaData();

                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your_files.zip");
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

                 Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
                 Files.createDirectories(dir);

                 Path file = dir.resolve("employee_custom_file" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                 /*try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(file))) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
                 }*/
                 ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file);
                 zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                 try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(zos)) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);
                 }


                 logger.info("Employee File Generated");



                 /*===========================================================================*/
                 /*    Code to generate a company CSV file                                      */ 
                 /*===========================================================================*/

                pstmtCompany = conn.prepareStatement(getCompanySQL);
                pstmtCompany.setString(1, requestID);
                rsCompany = pstmtCompany.executeQuery();

                ResultSetMetaData rsmdFacts = rsCompany.getMetaData();


                 Path filecompany = dir.resolve("company_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                 try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(filecompany))) {
                     writer.writeAll(rsCompany, true);
                 }

                 logger.info("Company CSV File Generated");


                 /*===========================================================================*/
                 /*    Code to generate a building CSV file                                 */ 
                 /*===========================================================================*/

                 pstmBuilding = conn.prepareStatement(getBuildingSQL);
                  pstmBuilding.setString(1, requestID);
                  rsBuildings = pstmBuilding.executeQuery();

                   ResultSetMetaData rsmdBuildings = rsBuildings.getMetaData();


                    Path fileBuildings = dir.resolve("building_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
                     try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(fileBuildings))) {
                         writer.writeAll(rsBuildings, true);
                     }

                    logger.info("Buildings CSV File Generated");




                }
            catch(Throwable th) {
                throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
            }
            finally {
                //resource Closing statements

            }   



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ZipEntry constructor expects either a String or another ZipEntry, check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html).

The CSVWriter, assuming you're using opencsv, expects a class that implements the Writer interface, check [here](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html).

So you should use (not tested):

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.toString());
```

and

```
try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Marcus Vinicus da Silva  I made the following changes `ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getFileName().toString());zos.putNextEntry(entry);try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
writer.writeAll(rsDemo, true);}` and I don't see zip file getting generated over there. What could be the reason? Other two files are getting generated in CSV format as before since I haven't made changes related to Zip conversion over there.